# What is the meaning of 飲んどけ?

Tags: translation, words, meaning, copywriting

I came across this Japanese tv commercial. Video and transcript are given below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOuwA6rtKsM

http://www.suntory.co.jp/news/article/12494.html

My question is: what's the meaning of 最初にこれ飲んどけって…ありますか? I think the key is to break down 飲んどけ but I don't know how this comes about. Seems to me it's made from 飲む (past) + どけ, but I can find only どける in dictionary and the combined meaning doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's a contracted form of 飲んで + おけ, with おけ being the imperative form of おく.

Comment: See also: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13892/, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18157/, and especially http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3141/.

Comment: The posts you mentioned are very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Shall we close this as a duplicate, then?  (Of which post?)