# What is the function of おけ in this sentence? 記しておけ

Tags: subsidiary-verbs

> 記して**おけ**

what is the role of おけ in this sentence.

Another sentence

> 放って**おけ**

Comment: Do you understand what 記しておく or 放っておくmean? 記しておけ and 放っておけ are just the corresponding imperatives.

Comment: Related/ Duplicate: [しとけ and sentence translation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13892/%e3%81%97%e3%81%a8%e3%81%91-and-sentence-translation)